# Count total amount of parts in a dataset

Tags: excel, sorting, calculation

I have the attached Dataset and would like to count the total amount for each part.
How can I do that in Excel ? :)

Feel free to directly edit the spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11p9aj_QUhnPMCeXKrZ6-bIZ-v8PTLw6hKDtOmxQHELQ/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you ! :)

[Pic of the Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMGoV.png)

Comment: Use `UNIQUE` Formula for `PART` --> `=UNIQUE(B5:B13)` and for `AMOUNT` use formula --> `=SUMIF(B5:B13,G5,C5:C13)` . I have already updated in the link!

Comment: For your information, Excel is **not** Google Sheets. For demonstration purposes I added an GS-alternative using `QUERY()`.

Comment: Alternatively you can use this for the `AMOUNT` as well  `=SUM(FILTER(C5:C13,E11=B5:B13))`

Answer (score 0):

[Mayukh Bhattacharya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8162520/mayukh-bhattacharya)'s Answer:

---

Use a `UNIQUE` Formula for PART → `=UNIQUE(B5:B13)`
For `AMOUNT`, use the formula `=SUMIF(B5:B13,G5,C5:C13)`.

---

###### I have already updated in the link!